# Using :Connect I keep getting msg 911 - database [dbname] does not exist

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a two part T-SQL script, the first part runs against a database on a different server, the second part is supposed to run on the local PC. I'm using `SQLCMD` mode and the `:Connect` keyword but every time I execute the command `SSMS` tells me it can't find the remote database in the local section of my code.

> Connecting to localhost...
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
> Database 'MYDBNAME' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
> Disconnecting connection from localhost...

I'm obviously in the localhost section of the code so why does it want to find the remote server database?

Thanks,

Mike F.

Comment: Can you post the script snippet where you get error ? you can use `:CONNECT (local)` to connect to local instance. If you want to connect to a different server then you have to use `:CONNECT server1\instance1`. Refer to [this example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/)

Comment: Are you sire you are typing the database name right ? Do you have more than one instance of SQL Server running locally?

Comment: I have validated the DB name is correct, if I comment out the :Connect section in the 2nd half of my code the script runs without error.  There are two instances on the remote server but I've ensured that I've connected to the correct instance at the start of the script by using :Connect Servername\ which connects to the default instance.

Comment: I ended up breaking the script into two separate scripts since my project was on hold while I researched the issue. Thanks hbrock for trying to help.